# CI / CD: Principles for deployment of environments

Tags: jenkins, automation, workflow, devops, continuous-deployment

I am not a developer, but reading about CI/CD at the moment. Now I am wondering about good practices for automated code deployment. I read a lot about the deployment of code to a pre-existing environment so far.

My question now is whether it is also good-practice to use e.g. a Jenkins workflow to deploy an environment from scratch when a new build is created. For example for testing of a newly created build, deleting the environment again after testing.

I know that there are various plugins to interact with AWS, Azure etc. that could be used to develop a job for deployment of a virtual machine.
There are also plugins to trigger Puppet to deploy infra (as code) and there are plugins to invoke an infrastructure orchestration.
So everything is available to be able to deploy the infrastructure and middleware before deploying code (with some extra effort of course).

Is this something that is used in real life? How is it done?

The background of my question is my interest in full automation of development with as few clicks as possible, and cost saving in a pay-per-use model by not having idle machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question now is whether it is also good-practice to use e.g. a Jenkins workflow to deploy an environment from scratch when a new build is created

Yes it is good practice to deploy an environment from scratch. Like you say, Jenkins and Jenkins pipelines can certainly help with kicking off and orchestrating that process depending on your specific requirements. Deploying a full environment from scratch is one of the hardest things to automate, and if that is automated, it implies that a lot of other things are also automated, such as infrastructure, application deployments, application configuration, and so on.

> Is this something that is used in real life?

Yes, definitely. A lot of shops do this. The simpler your environments, the easier it is, and therefore, a startup with one backend app would have relatively little trouble achieving this valhalla state. But even the creation of the most complex environments--with hundreds of interdependent applications--can be fully automated; it just takes more time and effort.

> The background of my question is my interest in full automation of development with as less clicks as possible and cost saving in a pay-per-use model by not having idling machines.

Yes, definitely. The "spin up and destroy" strategy benefits all hosting models (since, after full automation, no one ever has to wait for someone to manually provision an environment), but those using public clouds see even larger benefits in terms of cost (vs always leaving AWS environments running, for example).

> I appreciate your thoughts.

Not a problem. I will advise that this question doesn't fit stackoverflow's question and answer sweet spot super well, since it is quite general. In the future, I would recommend chatting with your developers, finding folks who are excited about this sort of thing, and formulating more specific questions when you all get stuck in the weeds on something. Welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

All is being used in various combinations; the objective is to deliver continuous value to end user. My two cents:

**Build & Release**
It depends on what you are using. I personally recommend to use what is available with the tool. For example, VSTS (Visual Studio Team Services) offers complete CI/CD pipeline. But if you have a unique need which can only be served by Jenkins then you must use that and VSTS offers that out of the box.

**IAC (Infrastructure as code)**
In addition to Puppet etc. You can take benefits of AZURE ARM (Azure Resource Manager) Template to Build and destroy an environment. Again, see what is available out of the box with the tool set you have.

**Pay-per-use**
What I have personally used is Azure Dev/Test Labs and have the code deployed to that via CI/CD pipeline. Later setup Shutdown policy on the VM so it will auto-start and auto-shutdown based on time provided. This is a great feature to let you save cost on the resources being used and replicate environments.

For example, UAT environment might not needed until QA is signed off. But using IAC you can quickly spin up the environment automatically and then have one-click deployment setup to deploy code to UAT.